# Converting Laravel validation message dot syntax into array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'am using Laravel on server side. Let's imagine our controller receive two fields `url` [string] and `data` [array with index `head`]. We can validate data and customize errors messages with

```
$this->validate($request, [

    'url' => 'required',
    'data.head' => 'required',

], [

    'url.required' => 'The :attribute field is required',
    'data.head.required' => 'The :attribute field is required',
]);
```

If validation fails, Laravel send back response with json data

```
{
    "url": ["The url field is required"],
    "data.head": ["The data.head field is required"]
}
```

How we can convert response data to send json, as below?

```
{
    "url": ["The url field is required"],
    "data": {
        "head": ["The data.head field is required"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has an helper called [array_set](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-array-set) that transform a dot based notation to array.

I don't know how you send the errors via ajax, but you should be able to do something like that:

```
$errors = [];
foreach ($validator->errors()->all() as $key => $value) {
  array_set($errors, $key, $value);
}
```

Edit:
But apparently, you should be able to not use the dot notation by [Specifying Custom Messages In Language Files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-error-messages) like this example:

```
'custom' => [
    'email' => [
        'required' => 'We need to know your e-mail address!',
    ],
],
```

Comment: I'am confusing. Why Laravel did not do converting dot syntax in response automatically?

Comment: I edited, my answer. I'm guessing, Laravel keeps the format that you specified. At least, that make sense to me, but don't see the point of using dot notation afterward.

Comment: Thank you for answear, of course I know about custom messages in separate files, but it is not decide my problem. I will use messages transformation before sending back.

Comment: Sorry, what I try to meant is, If you use the array notation, laravel _should_ return the errors messages as array.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript

Loop on errors

```
error: function (errors) {
    $.each(errors['responseJSON']['errors'], function (index, error) {
        var object = {};
        element = dotToArray(index);
        object[index] = error[0];
        validator.showErrors(object);
    });
}
```

convert in dot notation into array notation. i.e **abc.1.xyz into abc[1][xyz]**

```
function dotToArray(str) {
    var output = '';
    var chucks = str.split('.');
    if(chucks.length > 1){
        for(i = 0; i < chucks.length; i++){
            if(i == 0){
                output = chucks[i];
            }else{
                output += '['+chucks[i]+']';
            }
        }
    }else{
        output = chucks[0];
    }

    return output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still a valid question but to create a custom validation using dot notation in laravel, you can specify the array like this in your validation.php

```
'custom' => [
        'parent' => [
            'children' => [
                'required' => 'custom message here'
            ]
        ]
```

This will be the **parent.children** property.

see ya.

Answer (score 0):

```
key = key.replace(/\./g, '[') + Array(key.split('.').length).join(']');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

On the PHP side, you can use the [`undot`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-undot) function of the Collection class:

```
collect($errors->toArray())->undot()
```