# How to expand a dot notation array into a full multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

In my Laravel project, I have a dot notation array which I need to convert to a multi-dimensional array.

**The array is something like this:**

```
$dotNotationArray = ['cart.item1.id' => 15421a4, 
                 'cart.item1.price' => '145',
                 'cart.item2.id' => 14521a1,
                 'cart.item2.price' => '1245'];
```

**How can I expand it to an array like:**

```
    'cart' => [
        'item1' => [
            'id' => '15421a4',
            'price' => 145
        ],
        'item2' => [
            'id' => '14521a1',
            'price' => 1245,
        ]
    ]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089729/converting-laravel-validation-message-dot-syntax-into-array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Laravel 6+ you can use [`Arr::set()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-set) for this:

> The Arr::set method sets a value within a deeply nested array using "dot" notation:

```php
    use Illuminate\Support\Arr;


    $multiDimensionalArray = [];

    foreach ($dotNotationArray as $key => $value) {
        Arr::set($multiDimensionalArray , $key, $value);
    }

    dump($multiDimensionalArray);
```

If you are using Laravel 5.x you can use the [`array_set()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-set) instead, which is functionally identical.

**Explanation:**

`Arr::set()` sets value for a key in dot notation format to a specified key and outputs an array like `['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 200]]]`. so you can loop over your array keys to get a multidimensional array.